# what is indexpath for UICollectionView's supplementaryView or decorationView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

What does `indexpath` mean for UICollectionView's supplementaryView or decorationView?

```
layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath: 
layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/Reference/Reference.html) says :

> It is up to you to decide how to use the indexPath parameter to
>   identify a given supplementary view. Typically, you use the
>   elementKind parameter to identify the type of the supplementary view
>   and the indexPath information to distinguish between different
>   instances of that view.

Same for decoration views.

In other words there is absolutely no correlation between a cell indexPath which corresponds to a position in the data source, and the indexPath of the supplementary or decoration view which corresponds to whatever you want.